# MongoDB check if an embedded document is empty?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document and I need to return name who has no votes

```
user:
{ 
    'user_id': (id), 
    'name': (name),  
    'votes': {
    (vote_type): (No.of votes of this type)
    }, 
}
```

I tried with **db.user.find({votes: null},{name:true}).pretty()**. No results show up. How do I fix this. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

By default in MongoDB if a field is unpopulated MongoDB won't create the property for that document so you should be able to test if it [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

`db.user.find({votes: {$exists: false}},{name: true}).pretty()`

If you are setting it to `null` though you should be able to query for it as you described with [checking for `null`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls):

`db.user.find({votes: null},{name: true}).pretty()`

If neither works you might be storing an empty object `{}` by default and will need to check for that:

`db.user.find({votes: {}},{name: true}).pretty()`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the elements and add to those some new field f.e. "withNoVotes".

```
db.user.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  if(doc.votes) {
    for(var voteType in votes) {
       if(votes[voteType] && votes[voteType] > 0) {
          db.user.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {withNoVotes: true}});
          break;
       }
    }
  }
});
```

Now find them using usual query to find by this new field

```
db.user.find({withNoVotes: true});
```